# Publish Embedded Document Array to Meteor

Tags: meteor

I have meteor application made up of "notepads", each containing an array of "notes" which can be inserted into at any position, deleted from or have rows edited. This array is contained within an object with a variety of other information (ex. name, users, etc). Each object in my primary document will contain one of these arrays. For example:

```
{
  "_id": "1234",
  "name": "NotePad123",
  "notes": [ {note: "this is my first test note"},
             {note: "this is my second test note"},
             {note: "this is my third test note"} ]
},{
  "_id": "4321",
  "name": "NotePad321",
  "notes": [ {note: "noteA"},
             {note: "noteB"},
             {note: "noteC"} ]
}
```

Is there any way I can pass the "notes" as its own collection to my client so that the client can directly edit it as if it were not embedded? I am worried about a performance hit if I need to be passing the full notes array to the server every time I want to update it as there may be many updates it could become quite large.

I realize that I could create a new document and reference it, [as described here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-referenced-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/), but this could become quite hectic with many "notepads" as ordering is important and I will have many rows associated with each of my primary objects.

Comment: that is where the choice of denormalization or not must be made for defining your DB schema: 
if you expect many notes items, but the notepad always has the same notes, or at least they don't chnage as often, then it may be wise to have notes in its own collection.

Comment: look into this :
http://blog.mongodb.org/post/87200945828/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1 for more info on denormalization

Comment: I expect every notepad to have a unique set of notes, but the set of notes could be on the order of 100's-1000's. I also worry about quick updates to the set of notes. I'm getting the feeling that I simply need the set of notes to be it's own collection with a reference to the notepad (much like I would have done in an SQL DB).

Comment: Due to optimistic UI you probably don't need to worry too much about the actual DB performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a client-side collection that you put the notes in. Then, call a method to make the changes once you want to save.

Here's how you make a client-side collection:

`var notes = new Meteor.Collection(null)`

Comment: This is a possible solution, but I'd prefer to be saving note lines in real time so that if a user navigates away from the page everything is already saved (except perhaps the line they were currently editing).

Comment: You can be making a method call after each line, then on the server aggregate the results and put it in the notes object.

Comment: This is basically what I ended up doing. Though I did a standard publish/subscribe so that the user could see notes updated in real time.

I then created updated, insert and delete method calls to the server which include only a single note and its index. This means we only pass a single note 'across the wire'. The server then pulls the note array, updates the specified note, then sets it in the DB.

Overall pretty simple, but I had thought I was going to have to aggregate client side then send the full array back across, which this solution doesn't require.